# How to improve Video performance in react-native?

Tags: ios, react-native, cdn, react-native-video, flatlist

We have developed a Social media application in react-native but after development, we are facing an issue with video performance as especially download speed, is taking more time.  We used CDN and for video, we are using the react-native-video library. 
some of my team members are saying that for performance and video speed we need to move to Native iOS (using Swift).

We want to achieve video performance in react-native only, Is there any solution?